# C - Passing pointers as parameters

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters, subroutine

Here's what I've coded:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add(int *a, int i){
    while(i != 0){
        a++;
        i--;
    }
}

int main(){
    int a = 6;
    add(&a, 4);
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the result

```
a = 6
```

The result I'm expecting is `10`, of course, but I don't understand why `a` isn't modified when I pass it as a pointer in my `add` function...

Comment: Replace `a++;` with `*a++;`. The way you're doing it, you're incrementing the value of the pointer, not the value of what the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: @AntonH I probably should have mentioned this, but I've tried that already... I get an error saying : `warning: value computed is not used`

Comment: `a` in `add()` _is modified_.  `add(&a, 4);` passed a _copy_ of the address of `main()`'s `a` to `add()`.  The address `main()`'s `a` is not affected by the `add()` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the function there is advanced the pointer itself instead of incrementing the value pointed to by the pointer. Change the function the following way

```
void add(int *a, int i){
    while(i != 0){
        ( *a )++;
        i--;
    }
}
```

Or the expression statement `( *a )++;` can be substituted for `++*a;`

Also the function could be more safe if the second parameter had type `unsigned int`. Otherwise you have to check the sign of the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You function should be like this

```
void add(int *a, int i){
    while(i != 0){
        (*a)++; // deference the value and increment it.
        i--;
    }
}
```

with this

/* move the pointer to the next location */

> a++;

Answer (score 2):

AntonH's comment above is the right answer.

I'll expand it:

```
void add(int *a, int i){
    while(i != 0){
        a++;
        i--;
    }
}
```

You have defined 'a' as a pointer to an int (int*). Anything you do on 'a' such as '++'ing it is done on the pointer, not on the pointed value.

You should, therefore, replace `a++` with `(*a)++` to increase "what is pointed by a"